# Можно ли сделать на css что бы границы в разные стороны были выгнуты?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева выгнутая справа втянутая такое можно сделать используя css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант..

Использовать эти согнутые части, как фон для "вспомогательных" блоков (`.left`, `.right`).

```css
body {
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  min-width: ;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.left, .content, .right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7pRP.png');
}

.right {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzvnn.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur semper, turpis vitae semper malesuada, mauris nisi interdum neque, ut ultrices lectus quam quis nibh.
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что задний фон может поменяться?)

Comment: Под словом "задний фон" вы что имеете ввиду?

Comment: Сине-зеленая хрень с оборудованием

Comment: Суть в том, что правая сторона имеет прозрачность, а не красный цвет) Красный только у body

Comment: Угу, зато справа закрашено синим))

Comment: Так на примере вроде так же, не?

Comment: на примере справа явно картинка (видно переход в полупрозрачную область), к тому же кто знает что завтра заказчику в голову взбредет))

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через `border-radius` и `radial-gradien`.

Примерно так:

```css
.wapper {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 40px;
}

.fig {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle 1px at 150% 50%, transparent, transparent 225px, white 0);
  background-size: 100% 200px;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 45px/100px 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='wapper'>
  <div class='fig'>

  </div>
</div>
```